# User Login Issue in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite, ios4

I have an app which communicates to webserver. This webserver has SQLite database on it.

User can log on to their account from the app.

I want to ensure that if user is already logged in from one device, he should not be able to log in at the same time from other device.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How about adding a row in the sqlitedb that sets a value to 1/0 when you log in? and if you're trying to log in while the variable is 1 you cant?

Comment: Yes, I thought of this solution but how will I reset the flag as user can directly exit the app and there is not way we can detect closing of app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little bit of trick can do the task:

```
For that you need to have some **Boolean variable** inside your **SQlite Table in server**. So, when you are successfully logged in make that boolean to true .And please check this variable value to be True or False when doing login.
```

If you are already logged in another app then that Bool would have become True which means you can do the login.

Hope this trick would help you a lot

Comment: Yes, I thought of this solution but how will I reset this flag as user can directly exit the app and there is not way we can detect closing of app.

Comment: For log out also you need to make another webservice....in which on successful logout you need to return the bool value to check whether user has successfully logged out or not. And then on success, update the Bool value to False. :)